# Android Room migration didn't properly handle (wrong type)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am changing existing database to Room and facing this error.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle:

#Expected#

sql_date=Column{name='sql_date', type='**TEXT**', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}

#Found#

sql_date=Column{name='sql_date', type='**DATETIME**', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}

Please help...

Comment: Can you please share your Entity class? May be the variable `type` you defined in Entity is of type Date and column required as String.

Comment: in Sqlite the column name was created with type DATETIME but I am not able to find any equivalent type in Room